# When I run serve command with lerna I got enormous of outputs rows

Tags: vue.js, webpack, lerna

Im using lerna to run `serve` command. this command call `vue/cli` which call `webpack` to analyze all the files and build the bundle.

So I run `lerna run serve --stream` in vue/cli application and I get output of lot of rows in webpack progress:

```
myapp-vue: <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% asset optimization
myapp-vue: <s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after asset optimization
myapp-vue: <s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after seal
myapp-vue: <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting
myapp-vue: <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting HtmlWebpackPlugin
myapp-vue: <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting vue-cli:pwa-html-plugin
myapp-vue: <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting CopyPlugin
myapp-vue: <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
```

What can I do to not have all the rows? (just to have in one line - every time the line will erase and have new information) and I don't want to lose the webpack progress. maybe to create a buffer for every 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to write some kind of debounce-throttle for stdout. Or run gnu-screen with custom config. `screen -c ./lerna-screen`

But multiview package did the trick for me. It outputs spawned processes to independent columns

`npm i multiview -D`

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "multiview [npm run dev:app] [npm run dev:web] -e",
    "dev:app": "lerna run dev --stream --no-prefix --ignore=@therobot/*-web",
    "dev:web": "lerna run dev --stream --no-prefix --scope=@therobot/*-web"
  }
}
```

[image]